# Unable to access control, created in JSView, from controller with View byId

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to display a VizFrame and my data are in a simple JSON format.
Both my view and controller are in JS. (I will start writing my view in XML going forward) because I see that is the way to go.

I get a blank page with the error: "setDataset of undefined". What am I missing?

My view code is this.

```js
createContent: function(oController) {
  var oSubHeader = new sap.m.Bar({
    contentLeft: [
      new sap.m.Button({
        icon: "sap-icon://nav-back",
        press: [oController.onNavBack, oController]
      })
    ],
    contentMiddle: [
      new sap.m.Label({
        text: "{i18n>app_subhead_2}"
      })
    ]
  });
  var oVizFrame = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame("VizFrameId", {
    width: "100%",
    height: "400px",
    vizType: "line"
  });
  var oPage = new sap.m.Page({
    title: "UI5 Assignment App",
    showSubHeader: true,
    subHeader: oSubHeader,
    content: [oVizFrame]
  });
  return oPage;
}
```

My corresponding controller is

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
  "sap/ui/core/routing/History",
  "sap/viz/ui5/controls/VizFrame",
  "sap/viz/ui5/data/FlattenedDataset"
], function (Controller, UIComponent, History, VizFrame, FlattenedDataset) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("Project_Tile_learning.Divya_tile_Project.controller.ProductDetailPage", {
    onNavBack: function () {
      var oHistory = History.getInstance();
      var sPreviousHash = oHistory.getPreviousHash();
      if (sPreviousHash !== undefined) {
        window.history.go(-1);
      } else {
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.navTo("homepage", true);
      }
    },
    onInit: function () {
      var sampleDatajson = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("json/PA.json");
      var oVizFrame = this.getView().byId("VizFrameId");
      var oDataset = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
        dimensions: [{
          name: "Year",
          value: "{Year}"
        }],
        measures: [{
          name: "Supplier",
          value: "{Supplier}"
        }, {
          name: "Liquor",
          value: "{Liquor}"
        }, {
          name: "Quantity",
          value: "{Quantity}"
        }],
        data: {
          path: "/items"
        }
      });
      oVizFrame.setDataset(oDataset);
      oVizFrame.setModel(sampleDatajson);
      var oFeedValueAxis = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
        "uid": "valueAxis",
        "type": "Measure",
        "values": ["Supplier"]
      });
      var oFeedValueAxis1 = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
        "uid": "valueAxis",
        "type": "Measure",
        "values": ["Liquor"]
      });
      var oFeedValueAxis2 = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
        "uid": "valueAxis",
        "type": "Measure",
        "values": ["Quantity"]
      });
      var oFeedCategoryAxis = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
        "uid": "categoryAxis",
        "type": "Dimension",
        "values": ["Year"]
      });
      oVizFrame.addFeed(oFeedValueAxis);
      oVizFrame.addFeed(oFeedValueAxis1);
      oVizFrame.addFeed(oFeedValueAxis2);
      oVizFrame.addFeed(oFeedCategoryAxis);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update: JS View is deprecated** since UI5 v1.90. Use [Typed View](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/e6bb33d076dc4f23be50c082c271b9f0) instead.

---

When creating a control in JS view definition, always use `this.createId("myControl")`.

[From the doc:](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/91f262ef6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070)

> If you want to define IDs for controls inside a `JSView` to guarantee their uniqueness [...], you **cannot** give hardcoded IDs, but have to give the view the opportunity to add its own instance ID as a prefix. This is done by using the `View.createId(...)` method.

For the example above, this is done as follows:

```js
new sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame(this.createId("VizFrameId"), { /*...*/ });
```

Then in the controller, [`myView.byId`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.View#methods/byId) tries to access the control with view's own ID as a prefix, which will succeed this time since the control has an ID with the view ID as a prefix.